# Javascript little-endian Buffer to correct string output

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I have a Buffer in node 10 in variable msg that consoles out to: `[ Buffer f3 61 94 eb ]`.

When I do a `console.log(msg.toString('hex', 0, 4));` it prints out `f36194eb`.

I am actually needing it big-endian for that string, `eb9461f3`.  What is the easiest way to get this Buffer to this string output?

I had

```
let temBuff = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
temBuff.writeInt32BE(msg.readInt32LE(0));
let str = temBuff.toString('hex').toUpperCase();
console.log(str);
```

that does what I want but this seems excessive for flipping this little-endian buffer to the needed string.

Comment: I don't have a Node environment in front of me at the moment, but have you tried chaining with Buffer's native in-place [swaps](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_swap32), e.g. `temBuff.swap32().toString('hex').toUpperCase();`? To clarify, I haven't tested this and it may fall on its face.